# Why is n^2 + 2n + 2 equal to O(n^2)?

Tags: big-o

I'm learning about the Big-O notation, and I found an example that I can't simplify.

Why is n^2 + 2n + 2 = O(n^2)?

Comment: Presumably that is “Why does O(n^2 + 2n + 2) equal O(n^2)?”

Comment: Yes, I fixed it @user2864740

Comment: As this question required quite a few edits, and someone reviewing your original question marked it even as _Unsalvageable_, I suggest you have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as reference for future questions ;) – and also don't forget to accept one of the answer(s) if it answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An algorithm's running time (time complexity) is usually expressed as a function of the size of the input.

f(n) = n<sup>2</sup> + 2n + 2 where `n` is the size of the input

The Big-O notation is now used to express the asymptotic behavior of the complexity (the function) when the input size or `n` increases drastically. (This is of interest because the running time for small inputs is usually inconsequential).

Simply put, by looking at the function's terms and assuming `n` to be very large

- n<sup>2</sup> is a quadratic growth
- 2n grows with a small constant factor, and is a linear growth
- 2 is a constant and is therefore negligible

it becomes apparent that the n<sup>2</sup> term dominates and contributes the most to the time complexity, thus O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 4):

When talking about asymptotic notation you usually use really big values of `n` and you try to find by what mathematical function is your program bounded.

In this case, you have 2 functions `n^2` and `2n` (let's ignore the constant for now).

If you plot the graphs of [these](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5E2%2C+2n) you can see the following:

[image: n^2 vs 2n]

Although `2n` is slightly higher than `n^2` at the beginning, once `n` goes to infinity, [`2n` will always be lower than `n^2`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5E2%2C+2n+for+n%3D0..10000)

[image: n^2 vs 2n closer to infinity]

So if your method has a complexity of `O(n^2 + 2n)`, it doesn't really matter that much (or it's negligible) when `n` goes to infinity the value of `2n`, because your program will always be bound by `n^2`. You can apply the same reasoning to why a constant doesn't matter that much, even if it's a huge one.

Also, in asymptotic notation, you often do this "simplification" when you have sums, which is the case. However, this would be different if the complexity was `O(n^2 * 2n)`, which if I'm not mistaken would end up being `O(n^3)` - constants don't matter, so we can get rid of the `2` and then you have `n^2 * n`.

Comment: Thanks, my wolfram alpha fu is not great, was looking for a way to do this. Will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but for me, it was a bit complicated, a recommendation, maybe a bit more simpler?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want a simpler example? Or you prefer a simpler explanation?

Comment: A simpler explanation for me would work better, when I saw the 3 paragraphs, I sort of avoided them because they made your answer look boring. I think only the 3rd paragraph as an answer would've been very simple and to the point

Comment: yeah I guess different people come to stackoverflow for different reasons. It's hard to tailor an answer for everyone. I'm used to writing complete answers that have a proper explanation and not just one sentence answer that usually sprouts more questions. Of course, these might be deemed boring by some, but since it got 3 votes while the accepted answer has only 1, I'll stick to this style as it seems more relevant to more people.

Comment: Sure, I'm not trying to change the way how you write, but thank for the answer!

Comment: @Fred 1 of those 3 up-votes for your answer is from me  I like your “lengthy” explanation, and in particular found the references to the function graphs a good idea and helpful.  If you can, I suggest to include pictures of those graphs as embedded images in your answer and keep, but shorten the links as they currently disturb the reading flow. I think it’s always good to have different types of answers - the up-votes can then single out the most helpful. Actually, I’m still hoping for an answer which uses a purely mathematical approach or proof. I’d find that then very cool.

Comment: @IvoMori for sure I will